# Как запустить jar в Android?

Tags: java, android, linux

Волнует вопрос запуска JAR в Android. Я скомпилировал Java в jar. Через штатный openjdk все работает, а вот через Android отказывается. Хотя Android может запускать JAR файлы, кидаю код `/system/bin/media`

```
#!/system/bin/sh
# Script to start "media_cmd" on the device, which has a very rudimentary
# shell.
#
base=/system
export CLASSPATH=$base/framework/media.jar
exec app_process $base/bin com.android.commands.media.Media "$@"
```

Сам main.java - обычный хелловорлд для теста. Компилировал так:

```
 ~ # javac main.java
 ~ # jar cvmf MANIFEST.MF main.jar MyClass.class
 ~ # java -jar main.jar
It works!
```

Запускать пробовал так:

```
  ~ # base=/system CLASSPATH=./main.jar /system/bin/app_process
```

Но не работает. Как запустить JAR в Android, без сторонних средств вроде JBDE или J2ME?

Comment: Скорей всего никак, у Android Runtime и JVM фундаментальные отличия: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36335365

Answer (score -1):

Начнём с того что jar не запустить в телефоне(потому что это архиватор), но можно это попробовать запустить на эмуляторе в телефоне. Можете в Google Play поискать спец приложения которые позволят запускать подобные файлы и архиваторы. Я конечно не эксперт, но можно попробовать через Kali LInux запустить.

Comment: так в Android есть JAR файлы, и они могут быть запущены, я кинул /system/bin/media в доказательство своих слов

Comment: @RandomDice779 jar-файлы из андроида не имеют никакого отношения к "компьютерным" jar-файлам, они устроены абсолютно по-другому

Comment: и как их тогда собирать и писать?